# PHPmailer is not working on live server using gmail smtp with cakePHP 3

Tags: php, email, smtp, phpmailer

I use cakePHP 3, when I moved my app to server, it stopped sending emails, 
I am using gmail smtp server. I tried with SSL connect to smtp.gmail.com on port 465, still not working. Also variable `$mail->SMTPDebug  = on;` is making some troubles.

My send function is this:

```
  public function send($to, $subject, $message) {
    $sender = "me@me.com"; // this will be overwritten by GMail

    $header = "X-Mailer: PHP/".phpversion() . "Return-Path: $sender";
    $header .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
    $header .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8\r\n";

    $mail = new \PHPMailer();

    $mail->IsSMTP();
    $mail->Host = "aspmx.l.google.com";
    $mail->SMTPAuth = true;
    $mail->SMTPSecure = "ssl";
    $mail->Port = 25;
    $mail->SMTPDebug  = on; // turn it off in production
    $mail->Username   = "........";
    $mail->Password   = "........";

    $mail->From = $sender;
    $mail->FromName = "From Me";

    $mail->AddAddress($to);

    $mail->IsHTML(true);
    $mail->CreateHeader($header);

    $mail->Subject = $subject;
    $mail->Body    = nl2br($message);
    $mail->AltBody = nl2br($message);

    // return an array with two keys: error & message
    if(!$mail->Send()) {
        return array('error' => true, 'message' => 'Mailer Error: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo);
    } else {
        return array('error' => false, 'message' =>  "Message sent!");
    }
}
}
```

my error is this:

```
Use of undefined constant on - assumed 'on' [APP/Controller/Component/EmailComponent.php, line 30]

Undefined variable: errno [ROOT/vendor/phpmailer/class.smtp.php, line 182]

Undefined variable: errstr [ROOT/vendor/phpmailer/class.smtp.php, line 183]
```

Is is possible that webhosting on which I have page is blocking it?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's some misunderstanding of basic PHP syntax happening here. Have you tried [reading the manual](http://php.net/manual/en/langref.php)?

In this case, `on` (as well as being just plain invalid PHP) is not a valid value for `SMTPDebug`, even if you make it a string. Try setting it to `2`, as [the docs suggest](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting).

Your code is something of a mess - you're trying to break bits of PHPMailer (don't try to set headers yourself like that, let PHPMailer do it properly); you've based your code on an obsolete example, and are using an old version of PHPMailer; You're talking to the wrong address to send out through gmail - it should be `smtp.gmail.com`; You're trying to use SSL on a non-SSL port; You're putting HTML tags into the plain text version.

There's just too much wrong here to be worth fixing, so I suggest you start again with a [clean, working example](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/blob/master/examples/gmail.phps), and update to [the latest PHPMailer](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer).

As far as problems connecting to gmail go, this is also very well covered by the troubleshooting guide and by many other questions on SO.

Comment: If your device or application supports SSL - connect to smtp.gmail.com on port 465.

If your device or application does not support SSL - connect to aspmx.l.google.com on port 25.

this is what I saw in https://support.google.com/a/answer/176600?hl=en
so it depends on SSL support

Comment: Right, and the script in the question connects to `aspmx.l.google.com` using SSL on port 25, i.e. it's wrong. The clue is in the hostname - it contains `mx`, indicating that it's an inbound server, not outbound. Google won't let you send without auth (they're not a spam gateway), and you don't want to use auth without encryption, so that port and that host are both out of the question.

Answer (score 0):

Edit your lines like below:

```
$mail->Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
$mail->Port = 587;
```

It should work now.

Answer (score 0):

In line `$mail->SMTPDebug  = on; // turn it off in production`

`on` must be in quotes: `'on'`

**UPDATE:**

In the [class.phpmailer.php](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/blob/master/class.phpmailer.php) (from line nr. 315) there is description of the SMTPDebug values: it is integer from 0 to 4.

```
 // 0 - No output
 // 1 - Commands
 // 2 - Data and commands
 // 3 - As 2 plus connection status
 // 4 - Low-level data output
```

Comment: Quoting fixes the error, but it's still not a valid value for `SMTPDebug`.